# How can I fix an error when installing firebase tools using cmd? It shows the error below

Tags: node.js, firebase

Рow can I fix an error when installing Firebase tools using cmd?
It shows the error below.

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...Pzt6CFg==","shasum":"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ishmo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-16T00_25_26_582Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Since February, `request` has been marked as deprecated. You're best bet here, is to switch to using something like [`superagent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent), which is currently maintained.